Smallest graph with orientable genus strictly greater than nonorientable genus
Given a graph $G$, define the orientable genus $\gamma(G)$ as the least $g$ such that $G$ embeds into the sphere with $g$ handles (Euler characteristic $\chi=2-2g$). Define the nonorientable genus $\overline\gamma(G)$ as the least $k$ such that $G$ embeds into the sphere with $k$ crosscaps (Euler characteristic $2-k$).
Since one handle is equivalent to two crosscaps in the presence of another crosscap, we easily get the bound $\overline\gamma(G)\le2\gamma(G)+1$. For $G=K_7$ this bound on $\overline\gamma(G)$ is tight – see this other answer – and this same example shows that there are graphs with $\gamma(G)<\overline\gamma(G)$.
But I have not been able to come up with a graph for which the reverse strict inequality holds – $\gamma(G)>\overline\gamma(G)$. The other graph in the linked answer $H=K_8-C_4$ "embeds in the Klein bottle but not the torus", i.e. $\gamma(H)=\overline\gamma(H)=2$, so does not answer my question.
What is the smallest graph by vertex count for which $\gamma(G)>\overline\gamma(G)$?

Don't know about smallest, but in Auslander, Brown, and Youngs, "The imbedding of graphs in manifolds," J. Math. and Mech. (1963), they show that projective-planar graphs can have arbitrarily large orientable genus.
